# Find the min and max value from count aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I attempted to determine the minimum and maximum values from the courses associated with employees using the count aggregate function. The relationship between courses and employees is many-to-many (m:m). However, an issue arises when I execute the stored procedure, as it triggers an error. I appreciate anyone who helps me solve the problem.

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

The stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_max_min_EmployeeCourses4
AS 
    SELECT
        c.course_name, 
        COUNT(ec.emp_id) AS total_emp
    FROM
        [dbo].[course_test] c
    LEFT JOIN
        employee_courses ec ON c.course_id = ec.course_id
    GROUP BY
        c.course_name
    HAVING
        total_emp = (SELECT MAX(total_emp) AS max_emp
                     FROM [dbo].[course_test] c2)
        OR total_emp = (SELECT MAX(total_emp) AS min_emp
                        FROM [dbo].[course_test] c3)
```

Comment: Your clauses in the `HAVING` should be in the `WHERE`. Why did you put them in the `HAVING` when they aren't performing an aggregate on an inner expression?

Comment: FYI the prefix `sp_` is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial / **S**ystem **P**rocedures. It should *not* be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: I used HAVING because I can't use WHERE with GROUP BY. Now, I replace the HAVING with the WHERE clause and I remove the GROUP BY but the problem appears is: An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: Why did you remove the `GROUP BY`? You *need* the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I cant use it with WHERE

Comment: Huh? The `GROUP BY` is a completely separate clause to the `WHERE`, like the `SELECT` and `FROM`.

Comment: Ok I used it now but the problem still appear : `An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.
`

Comment: Sounds like there's more going on that you're telling us then, as using an aggregate in a subquery in the `WHERE` won't generate that error. I suggest you take the time to provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: You cannot use an alias (like: `total_emp`) in the HAVING (or GROUP BY, or WHERE) clause.

Comment: @RehamAlmutairi: Specifying the complete error message (in text)  might solve a lot:  "**Column 'dbo.course_test.total_emp' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.**"  see: https://dbfiddle.uk/qDJOXqOX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two syntax errors in your query:

1. Standard SQL does not allow using aliases in the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses. SQL Server is compliant to the standard here. `total_emp` is not known in the `HAVING` clause, because the clause gets evaluated before the `SELECT` clause in which you define the alias.
2. The table `course_test` does not have a column called `total_emp`, so you cannot get the minimum or maximum value of it in the subqueries.

Instead, you can use `MIN OVER` and `MAX OVER` to get the minimum and maximum counts:

```
select course_name, total_emp
from
(
  select 
    c.course_name,
    count(ec.emp_id) as total_emp,
    min(count(ec.emp_id)) over () as min_count,
    max(count(ec.emp_id)) over () as max_count
  from [dbo].[course_test] c
  left join employee_courses ec on c.course_id = ec.course_id
  group by c.course_name
) with_min_and_max_count
where total_emp in (min_count, max_count);
```

Thank you for accepting my answer. I thought I'd add an alternative, though, just for you to see that there are other ways to write such a query where you want to refer to a query result again. You can use a common table expression (CTE aka `WITH` clause):

```
with counted as
(
  select 
    c.course_name,
    count(ec.emp_id) as total_emp
  from [dbo].[course_test] c
  left join employee_courses ec on c.course_id = ec.course_id
  group by c.course_name
)
select course_name, total_emp
from counted
where total_emp = (select min(total_emp) from counted)
   or total_emp = (select max(total_emp) from counted);
```